# Android exception when loading drawable resource

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using Jetpack Compose, and I am getting `Unknown command for: R` exception, when loading drawable inside Image

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.slaviboy.postbank, PID: 7155
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown command for: R
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> It seems it is problem when trying to load large SVG file, with long
> path data.

I was able to fix it by:

- splitting the map in to multiple segments (multiple paths)
- using https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to reduce number of precision
  [image]

Here is the final drawable source code, in case someone need it:
[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="280.3dp"
    android:height="144.3dp"
    android:viewportWidth="280.3"
    android:viewportHeight="144.3">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M51,76h-1a5,5 0,0 0,-2 -1,4 4,0 0,1 -1,0l-1,-1a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1,2 2,0 0,0 -1,-1 3,3 0,0 1,-1 -2h-3a5,5 0,0 1,-1 -2,4 4,0 0,0 -2,-1h-1l-1,1 -4,-2a18,18 0,0 1,-4 -2v-2a2,2 0,0 0,0 -2,11 11,0 0,0 -2,-2l-1,-2a5,5 0,0 0,0 -1,8 8,0 0,1 -2,-3v-2l-1,1v3a12,12 0,0 1,1 2,8 8,0 0,0 1,2c0,2 0,2 -1,0l-1,-1v-1l-1,-2v-2a3,3 0,0 1,-1 -2,2 2,0 0,0 -1,-2 1,1 0,0 1,-1 -2v-3a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1,1 1,0 0,0 0,-1v-1a6,6 0,0 0,1 -1,9 9,0 0,1 2,-2 11,11 0,0 0,1 -3l1,-1h2v-2a4,4 0,0 0,-1 -1l-1,-2a1,1 0,0 0,0 -1l1,-1v-2l-1,-2a9,9 0,0 1,-2 -1,3 3,0 0,0 -1,-1 18,18 0,0 1,-2 0h-6l-2,1a15,15 0,0 1,-3 1,10 10,0 0,0 -2,1 18,18 0,0 1,-5 2l1,-1a19,19 0,0 0,4 -2c1,-1 0,-1 -1,-1a1,1 0,0 1,-1 0l1,-2 3,-2a7,7 0,0 0,3 -1c1,0 1,-1 0,0a2,2 0,0 1,-2 0l-1,-1a5,5 0,0 1,4 -1,3 3,0 0,0 1,0h1v-1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -1h2a9,9 0,0 0,2 -1,26 26,0 0,1 5,-1 12,12 0,0 1,5 0l3,1a25,25 0,0 1,3 0,10 10,0 0,0 6,0 8,8 0,0 1,3 0,1 1,0 0,0 1,0 1,1 0,0 1,1 0,3 3,0 0,0 2,0 6,6 0,0 1,2 1,10 10,0 0,0 2,0c1,0 1,0 0,0v1a6,6 0,0 0,2 0l2,1h1a4,4 0,0 1,2 -1,3 3,0 0,1 2,0 5,5 0,0 0,2 0,2 2,0 0,1 2,0h1a5,5 0,0 1,1 0c2,-1 2,-1 1,-2l1,-1h2c0,1 0,0 0,0v2a1,1 0,0 1,1 0c-1,2 1,1 3,0a2,2 0,0 1,2 -1l-1,2a3,3 0,0 1,-3 1,5 5,0 0,0 -2,1 1,1 0,0 1,-1 0h-1l1,1h-1a11,11 0,0 1,-2 1h-1l-2,1c-3,1 -5,3 -4,4a2,2 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,0 0,0 1,0 12,12 0,0 1,2 1,13 13,0 0,0 3,1v4h1l2,-2 2,-2 2,-3 1,-1a4,4 0,0 0,1 -1,2 2,0 0,1 3,-2l2,2a1,1 0,0 1,0 1l1,1h1a15,15 0,0 0,2 -1l1,-1v1a1,1 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,0 0,1 0,1v3h1a2,2 0,0 1,2 1q1,1 -2,2a11,11 0,0 1,-6 1,7 7,0 0,0 -4,1 8,8 0,0 0,-2 1h2a7,7 0,0 1,2 0h1a4,4 0,0 1,-1 1v1a2,2 0,0 0,2 1h1,-1a5,5 0,0 1,-1 1,10 10,0 0,0 -2,1 2,2 0,0 1,-1 0l1,-1v-1a25,25 0,0 0,-3 1l-3,2 -3,2a5,5 0,0 0,-1 1,10 10,0 0,1 -2,1 2,2 0,0 0,-1 1c0,1 0,1 0,0l-1,2a3,3 0,0 1,-2 3,13 13,0 0,0 -4,3v3l-1,3 -1,-3a1,1 0,0 0,-1 -2,1 1,0 0,0 -1,0 3,3 0,0 1,-1 0,2 2,0 0,0 -2,-1 2,2 0,0 0,-1 1l-1,1a7,7 0,0 1,-2 -1,2 2,0 0,0 -2,0l-2,2a3,3 0,0 0,-2 1l-1,3v4c1,2 2,3 4,3l3,-2a1,1 0,0 1,1 -1h2l-2,3c-1,3 -1,3 1,3h3a13,13 0,0 1,0 3v3a4,4 0,0 0,2 1h1v1ZM54,38 L57,35v1l-1,1h1a1,1 0,0 0,1 0,1 1,0 0,0 1,0v-1a1,1 0,0 0,1 0c1,-1 -1,-2 -1,-1a1,1 0,0 1,-2 -1,1 1,0 0,0 0,-2h-3a7,7 0,0 1,-1 1h-1a3,3 0,0 0,-1 0v1a1,1 0,0 0,2 0h1a3,3 0,0 0,2 0h1l-1,1c-2,0 -2,1 -3,2l-1,2h1a5,5 0,0 0,1 -1ZM58,39 L59,38h-1c-2,1 -2,2 -1,2a5,5 0,0 0,1 -1ZM63,37h-2,2ZM71,67ZM69,66c-1,0 0,0 0,0ZM70,66v-1,1ZM71,66v-1,1c0,1 0,0 0,0ZM54,65h1c1,0 1,0 0,0a4,4 0,0 1,-1 0ZM60,65a2,2 0,0 0,-1 0,3 3,0 0,1 -1,0v-1h2c-1,-1 -1,-1 1,-1a5,5 0,0 1,3 1l-4,1ZM65,65v-1l1,1a1,1 0,0 1,-1 0ZM67,65v-1,1ZM56,63a3,3 0,0 0,-1 0v-1c1,-1 -1,0 -1,-1l-4,-1 -1,1 3,-1 4,1 2,2h-2ZM58,61h1,-1ZM60,60h1,-1ZM55,58v-1,1s1,0 0,0ZM56,56v-1l1,1c1,1 0,0 0,0h-1ZM55,56v-1,1ZM70,49ZM82,34 L83,33v1h-1c-1,0 0,0 0,0ZM81,33h-1l2,-2a10,10 0,0 1,2 -1c-1,1 0,1 1,1a1,1 0,0 1,0 1v1a10,10 0,0 1,-4 0ZM23,31 L22,30 24,31v1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 -1ZM22,25h1,-1ZM22,23c0,1 0,1 0,0ZM6,23h3a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0,8 8,0 0,0 -1,0h-1ZM79,18a5,5 0,0 1,-1 -2h-3a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0l2,-1h2a2,2 0,0 1,2 -1,2 2,0 0,0 1,0c1,0 1,0 0,0a2,2 0,0 0,0 -1,3 3,0 0,1 -1,-1 5,5 0,0 0,-2 -1l-1,-1a2,2 0,0 1,-2 1,6 6,0 0,0 -2,-1h-2l3,-2 1,-1 -1,1c-1,1 0,2 1,1a4,4 0,0 1,1 -1h2l3,1h1a4,4 0,0 0,1 1l1,2a1,1 0,0 0,1 1l1,1 -2,1 -1,-1v1a1,1 0,0 1,0 2h-2l1,1h-3ZM70,17a2,2 0,0 0,-1 0c-2,0 -2,0 -1,-1a2,2 0,0 1,2 -1l1,2h-1ZM53,12a10,10 0,0 1,-2 0l-1,-1h1l2,-1h-2v-1c-1,0 -1,0 0,0a6,6 0,0 1,4 -1h3v1h1l2,-1a4,4 0,0 1,-1 1v1l1,1h-1a3,3 0,0 1,-3 1,3 3,0 0,0 -2,0 3,3 0,0 1,-2 0ZM62,12 L63,11a2,2 0,0 1,1 0v1h-2ZM47,9 L48,8 54,7 55,8h-2a38,38 0,0 0,-5 2,1 1,0 0,1 -1,-1ZM64,9h-1v-1h2a5,5 0,0 1,2 -1v1l-3,1ZM68,8 L71,7c1,1 0,1 -1,1a9,9 0,0 0,-2 1v-1ZM76,7 L73,6v-1l2,1a4,4 0,0 0,3 0,11 11,0 0,1 2,0h1l-1,1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 0h-3ZM81,5a3,3 0,0 0,-2 0,3 3,0 0,1 -2,0l1,-1h2c-1,-1 0,-1 0,0l1,-1 3,-1a6,6 0,0 0,2 0c1,0 1,-1 0,0a17,17 0,0 1,-4 -1,121 121,0 0,1 13,-1h1l-2,1a19,19 0,0 1,-6 2,6 6,0 0,0 -2,0 7,7 0,0 1,-1 1,8 8,0 0,0 -2,1l-1,1 -1,-1ZM76,3v-1h3l-1,1a2,2 0,0 1,-2 0Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" />
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M75,144c-2,0 -2,-1 -2,-2h1a7,7 0,0 1,2 1,15 15,0 0,0 2,1h1,-3a4,4 0,0 1,-1 0ZM72,142a1,1 0,0 0,-1 0l-1,-1a2,2 0,0 0,0 -1c-1,0 -2,-1 -2,-3a3,3 0,0 0,-2 -1v-4a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1l-1,-1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 -2,3 3,0 0,0 0,-2v-2a15,15 0,0 0,-1 -5,54 54,0 0,1 0,-10 10,10 0,0 0,0 -3c-1,-1 -2,-3 -5,-4l-2,-2a17,17 0,0 0,-2 -3,8 8,0 0,1 -1,-2 8,8 0,0 0,-2 -3,2 2,0 0,1 -1,-2l1,-2v-1c-1,0 -1,-2 2,-4l1,-5v-1l-1,-1c-1,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 0,-2 1,-1h1a3,3 0,0 0,1 -1,3 3,0 0,1 2,-1 2,2 0,0 0,1 -1h1a4,4 0,0 0,0 3v-1h1v-2a1,1 0,0 1,2 1,7 7,0 0,0 4,1c1,-1 5,1 6,3a4,4 0,0 0,3 1c2,0 4,2 4,4a3,3 0,0 0,1 1l-1,2 -1,1h1c1,-2 2,-2 2,-1v1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0l1,1 1,-1h2l1,1 1,1h3l3,1a5,5 0,0 0,2 1l1,1a4,4 0,0 1,-1 4,12 12,0 0,0 -1,2 7,7 0,0 1,-1 1v2c0,3 -1,8 -3,9a2,2 0,0 1,-1 1h-1a4,4 0,0 1,-1 0,9 9,0 0,0 -2,2l-1,1a3,3 0,0 1,0 3,2 2,0 0,0 0,1 3,3 0,0 1,-1 2,25 25,0 0,0 -1,2c-1,1 -2,2 -3,1h-2v1a3,3 0,0 1,1 1v1a3,3 0,0 1,-2 2c-1,0 -2,0 -1,1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 1,2 2,0 0,1 -1,0v1a2,2 0,0 0,0 1h1a1,1 0,0 0,-1 1,2 2,0 0,1 0,1v2a2,2 0,0 0,0 1l1,2a3,3 0,0 0,-1 3l-1,1ZM81,141v-1,1h-1v-1h1c2,0 2,0 1,1h-1ZM70,74c0,-1 0,-1 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" />
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M151,122a1,1 0,0 1,-1 -2,2 2,0 0,0 0,-2 4,4 0,0 1,-1 -1,6 6,0 0,0 -1,-1 4,4 0,0 1,-1 -3,19 19,0 0,0 -2,-7 11,11 0,0 1,-1 -3l2,-5v-2a4,4 0,0 1,0 -2,2 2,0 0,0 -1,-1 11,11 0,0 1,-1 -2,5 5,0 0,0 -1,-3c-1,-1 -2,-2 -1,-4 1,-3 0,-5 -3,-4l-1,-1 -1,-1a2,2 0,0 0,-3 0l-2,1h-3a4,4 0,0 0,-2 0,4 4,0 0,1 -3,0c-2,0 -4,-2 -5,-4l-2,-3 -1,-1c0,-1 1,0 0,0v-1c1,0 1,0 0,0v-2a5,5 0,0 0,0 -6l1,-3a21,21 0,0 0,1 -2l3,-3a5,5 0,0 0,2 -2,4 4,0 0,1 2,-4 6,6 0,0 0,2 -1l1,-1a4,4 0,0 0,2 1l2,-1a9,9 0,0 1,6 -1,6 6,0 0,0 3,0h2a1,1 0,0 0,0 1v2a3,3 0,0 0,2 1l3,1a2,2 0,0 0,1 1,7 7,0 0,1 1,1l2,-1v-1a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1l3,1 7,1a3,3 0,0 1,1 0c2,0 1,2 2,3l2,4a23,23 0,0 0,1 3,3 3,0 0,1 1,1l1,3a5,5 0,0 1,1 2l2,2a7,7 0,0 1,2 3,2 2,0 0,0 1,1h3a18,18 0,0 0,3 -1h1v1l-2,4c-1,4 -2,4 -3,5a17,17 0,0 0,-3 3l-2,2c-2,3 -3,5 -1,8a3,3 0,0 1,1 2,5 5,0 0,0 0,2 2,2 0,0 1,-1 2l-2,2a3,3 0,0 0,-1 1,6 6,0 0,1 -1,2 6,6 0,0 0,-2 1,5 5,0 0,0 1,1c1,2 0,3 -2,4l-1,2v1a4,4 0,0 0,-1 1,20 20,0 0,1 -5,5l-2,1a4,4 0,0 0,-3 0h-2ZM139,84h1c1,0 0,0 0,0h-1ZM141,81Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" />
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="m163,50 l3,-1v-1l1,-2v-2h-2a1,1 0,0 1,-2 0h-4a3,3 0,0 1,-1 -2,1 1,0 0,0 0,-1v-1h2a2,2 0,0 1,1 -1,4 4,0 0,0 2,0h8v-1a9,9 0,0 0,-2 -2l-2,-1v-1s1,0 0,0l1,-1a2,2 0,0 0,0 -1l-2,1 -1,1v1h-2v-1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -1c0,-1 -3,2 -3,4v2h1,-2a5,5 0,0 1,-1 0l-2,1a1,1 0,0 0,-1 0v1l1,2h-2v-1c1,0 1,0 0,0 -1,-1 -2,-1 -2,-3a3,3 0,0 0,-2 -2,3 3,0 0,1 -1,-1 3,3 0,0 0,-1 -1,3 3,0 0,1 -2,0v-1a1,1 0,0 0,-1 1l5,4v1l-1,1v1l-3,-3 -2,-3h-2a4,4 0,0 1,-3 1c-1,-1 -2,0 -2,1a3,3 0,0 0,-1 1,3 3,0 0,1 -1,0l-1,2 -2,2a4,4 0,0 1,-2 1h-2a3,3 0,0 0,-2 -1v-3a7,7 0,0 0,0 -2l2,-2h5a4,4 0,0 0,0 -3l-1,-1c-2,0 -2,-1 0,-1a3,3 0,0 0,1 0l1,-1 2,-1a2,2 0,0 1,1 -1,7 7,0 0,0 2,-1 4,4 0,0 1,2 -1l1,-1a2,2 0,0 1,0 -2,2 2,0 0,1 1,-1v1l1,1a4,4 0,0 0,1 -1c0,1 0,2 -1,1h-1l1,1h1a2,2 0,0 1,2 0h3a1,1 0,0 0,1 0l2,-2c-1,-1 0,-1 1,-1h1v-1l-1,-1a4,4 0,0 1,2 0l3,-1h-3a3,3 0,0 1,-3 0v-3l1,-2c-1,-1 -1,-1 -2,1a7,7 0,0 1,-2 1,2 2,0 0,0 -1,1v1a2,2 0,0 0,1 1l-1,1a3,3 0,0 0,-1 2,3 3,0 0,1 -1,1h-1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -1,4 4,0 0,0 -1,-1v-1l-1,1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 0,2 2,0 0,1 -2,-1 5,5 0,0 0,0 -2l2,-1a9,9 0,0 0,3 -3,7 7,0 0,1 2,-2 4,4 0,0 0,1 -1h1l2,-1a9,9 0,0 1,3 -1,9 9,0 0,1 5,1 2,2 0,0 0,2 1c1,-1 5,1 5,1l-2,1h-4,1a3,3 0,0 1,1 1,3 3,0 0,0 2,2v-1h1c1,0 2,0 1,-1l1,-1h2v-1h3l3,-1h2a6,6 0,0 1,2 0h1l-1,-1h-1l7,1h1l-1,-1c-1,-1 -2,-2 0,-2 1,-1 2,0 3,1l1,3v1l2,-1a2,2 0,0 0,-1 -2,2 2,0 0,1 -1,-1L188,8c1,1 2,0 4,-1a3,3 0,0 1,1 0l2,-1L195,5a17,17 0,0 1,5 0,2 2,0 0,0 2,-1L202,3h-2c0,1 0,1 0,0h-2l-5,-2a3,3 0,0 1,3 1,4 4,0 0,0 2,0 1,1 0,0 0,1 0l4,1a4,4 0,0 1,2 1,7 7,0 0,0 3,0l3,1a5,5 0,0 1,-1 1c-2,1 -1,1 1,1a4,4 0,0 1,2 0,3 3,0 0,0 2,0 4,4 0,0 1,3 0,4 4,0 0,0 2,0 7,7 0,0 1,4 0l3,2h2a3,3 0,0 1,2 0,3 3,0 0,0 2,0L233,8h6a7,7 0,0 1,2 1h4l5,1h4a11,11 0,0 1,4 1l1,-1h1a39,39 0,0 1,7 1,13 13,0 0,0 3,1 9,9 0,0 1,2 1h2l3,1v1a5,5 0,0 1,-3 -1,3 3,0 0,1 -2,0h-1v1l1,1 2,1h-1l-2,1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 1h-1a1,1 0,0 0,-1 0,8 8,0 0,1 -2,0 3,3 0,0 0,-1 1l2,2a2,2 0,0 1,1 1,10 10,0 0,0 1,1v2a5,5 0,0 1,0 1,4 4,0 0,0 0,1l-2,-1a14,14 0,0 0,-1 -1,12 12,0 0,1 -2,-2l-1,-2a3,3 0,0 0,0 -2,3 3,0 0,1 1,-1l-1,-2a1,1 0,0 0,-1 1h-1a5,5 0,0 0,-2 0h-1a3,3 0,0 0,0 1l-1,1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 0,2 2,0 0,0 -2,0 15,15 0,0 1,-2 0l-3,1a4,4 0,0 0,-1 1,7 7,0 0,1 -1,2l1,1a4,4 0,0 0,3 0l3,3a3,3 0,0 0,1 1l1,6 -2,2a6,6 0,0 0,-1 0,5 5,0 0,0 -1,1v1l-1,1v1a7,7 0,0 0,1 1,6 6,0 0,1 2,2 2,2 0,0 1,1 1l-1,1h-1l-1,-1 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1,-1h-2a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -1,1 1,0 0,0 0,-1l-1,1a8,8 0,0 1,-2 1v1a6,6 0,0 0,2 1h3v1l-2,1 1,1a3,3 0,0 1,1 2,4 4,0 0,0 1,1l1,1v4c-1,3 -2,4 -4,5a11,11 0,0 1,-2 1,3 3,0 0,0 -2,1l-1,1v-1l-2,-1a3,3 0,0 0,-2 2l2,3a9,9 0,0 1,3 4,2 2,0 0,1 -2,3 2,2 0,0 0,-1 1l-1,1a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1,1 1,0 0,0 0,-1h-2l-3,-3 -1,1a9,9 0,0 1,0 2v2a5,5 0,0 1,1 1,5 5,0 0,0 2,2 5,5 0,0 1,2 3,21 21,0 0,1 0,2l-1,-1 -3,-4a3,3 0,0 0,-1 -2l-1,-2v-2a3,3 0,0 0,0 -2,15 15,0 0,1 -1,-2c0,-2 -1,-2 -2,-1a3,3 0,0 1,0 1l-1,-2 -2,-3a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -2l-2,-1a10,10 0,0 1,-2 1l-1,1 -1,1a3,3 0,0 0,-1 1,2 2,0 0,1 -1,1 2,2 0,0 0,-1 1,7 7,0 0,1 -1,1l-1,2 -1,5c-1,2 -1,2 -2,1a1,1 0,0 1,-1 -1,18 18,0 0,0 -1,-2l-3,-10s0,-2 -1,-1h-3,1v-1a2,2 0,0 1,-1 -1,3 3,0 0,0 -1,0l-1,-1a2,2 0,0 0,-2 -1,28 28,0 0,1 -7,0 4,4 0,0 1,-1 -1h-2l-2,-1 -2,-2 -2,-1a1,1 0,0 0,-1 1l1,1a7,7 0,0 1,1 2l1,1h1a1,1 0,0 1,0 1h2a5,5 0,0 0,1 -1h1a2,2 0,0 0,1 2l3,2a2,2 0,0 1,-1 1,7 7,0 0,0 -1,1l-3,3a3,3 0,0 0,-2 1,4 4,0 0,1 -1,1 38,38 0,0 1,-6 3l-1,-1a8,8 0,0 1,-1 -2,4 4,0 0,0 -1,-2 3,3 0,0 1,-1 -1,5 5,0 0,0 -1,-2 5,5 0,0 1,-1 -2,7 7,0 0,0 -1,-2l-3,-5h-1l-1,-1 -2,-2ZM183,44v-1a2,2 0,0 0,0 -2,4 4,0 0,1 -1,-1l1,-1a3,3 0,0 0,0 -1h-2l-1,-1 -1,-2a2,2 0,0 1,2 0v-1c-1,-2 -3,-2 -5,0v2a1,1 0,0 1,0 1,4 4,0 0,0 1,1c1,1 2,2 1,3v2l2,1h2a5,5 0,0 0,1 0ZM164,46v-1a1,1 0,0 0,1 0l-1,1ZM156,46 L155,45h1l2,1h-2ZM146,43 L145,42 147,43h-1ZM141,41v-2l1,1 -1,1ZM135,41h1,-1ZM141,38a1,1 0,0 1,1 -1v1h-1ZM130,29h1c1,-1 0,-1 -1,-1v-1l1,-1h1l-1,-2h-1a1,1 0,0 0,0 -1,2 2,0 0,1 1,-2v1h1v1h-1,1l2,3v1h1l-1,1 -1,1a97,97 0,0 0,-3 0ZM126,28a2,2 0,0 1,0 -1v-2a2,2 0,0 0,1 0l2,-1v1a2,2 0,0 0,-1 1l-1,1 -1,1ZM130,25ZM150,20v-1h1l-1,1ZM174,9 L173,8 174,7 175,5a9,9 0,0 1,3 0h3,-2a6,6 0,0 0,-3 2v3h-1a6,6 0,0 1,-1 -1Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" />
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.5"
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M265,132v-1a3,3 0,0 0,0 -1v-1a6,6 0,0 0,2 1h1l-2,2h-1ZM267,127 L266,126a3,3 0,0 1,-3 0v-1a1,1 0,0 0,0 -1,3 3,0 0,1 0,-1h-1v-2a5,5 0,0 0,-2 1v-1a5,5 0,0 0,-2 -1l-2,-1a17,17 0,0 0,-6 2,9 9,0 0,1 -3,0 16,16 0,0 0,-3 1l-2,1 -1,-2a3,3 0,0 0,1 -1,3 3,0 0,0 0,-2 11,11 0,0 1,0 -4,13 13,0 0,0 0,-3 3,3 0,0 1,1 -1l3,-2a16,16 0,0 1,3 -1,4 4,0 0,0 3,-3l1,-1h1a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1,3 3,0 0,0 1,-1 4,4 0,0 1,2 -1h1l2,1 2,-2a9,9 0,0 0,1 -1,2 2,0 0,1 2,0c2,0 2,0 1,1 -1,2 0,2 2,4a7,7 0,0 0,2 1,5 5,0 0,0 1,-1 4,4 0,0 0,1 -3l1,-3 1,1a5,5 0,0 0,1 2,5 5,0 0,1 0,4l1,2a11,11 0,0 1,2 2,19 19,0 0,0 1,3l1,1v2a9,9 0,0 1,-1 4l-3,3a5,5 0,0 0,-1 1,4 4,0 0,1 -1,1 5,5 0,0 0,-2 2l-2,1a3,3 0,0 0,-2 1h-1ZM175,112 L174,110a3,3 0,0 1,1 -2,3 3,0 0,0 0,-3l1,-3a8,8 0,0 0,4 -3v-1l1,1 -1,5 -2,5c0,2 0,3 -2,3h-1ZM186,108v-1l1,1h-1ZM188,107ZM175,99h1,-1ZM278,95 L275,93a2,2 0,0 0,-1 1l-1,1a4,4 0,0 1,-2 -1h-1a1,1 0,0 1,-1 0l1,-1v-1l-3,-2a9,9 0,0 0,-2 -1l-1,-1v-1l-1,-1a3,3 0,0 1,1 0,2 2,0 0,1 1,1 2,2 0,0 0,1 1h1a7,7 0,0 1,1 -1l1,-1 2,1 3,1a17,17 0,0 1,2 2l2,2v3ZM251,95h-1l1,1v-1ZM255,95a2,2 0,0 1,2 -1h1a5,5 0,0 0,-2 1h-1ZM248,95v-1a2,2 0,0 1,2 0h-1a5,5 0,0 0,0 1,2 2,0 0,1 -1,0ZM251,94h2v1l-2,-1ZM244,94a19,19 0,0 1,-3 -1,4 4,0 0,0 -1,0l-3,-1h7a3,3 0,0 0,0 1l2,1h-2ZM235,91a10,10 0,0 1,-3 -4,14 14,0 0,0 -1,-2 17,17 0,0 1,-1 -2,8 8,0 0,0 -2,-2l-1,-2a6,6 0,0 1,3 1,15 15,0 0,0 3,3 2,2 0,0 1,1 2,2 2,0 0,0 1,1l1,1a4,4 0,0 1,1 2l-2,2ZM187,91v-1l1,1h-1ZM251,91a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1,1 1,0 0,0 -1,-1v-1a5,5 0,0 0,1 -2,3 3,0 0,1 1,-2h2a3,3 0,0 0,2 -1v1a1,1 0,0 1,-2 0c-1,0 -3,1 -2,2h2a1,1 0,0 0,-1 2,3 3,0 0,1 1,1l-1,1a3,3 0,0 1,-1 -2l-1,1v2ZM246,88a2,2 0,0 0,-1 0,6 6,0 0,1 -3,0 20,20 0,0 1,-2 -4,1 1,0 0,1 1,-1h1a3,3 0,0 1,2 -1,3 3,0 0,0 1,-1 2,2 0,0 1,1 -1,4 4,0 0,0 1,-2h1a3,3 0,0 1,1 0l1,1 -1,1a2,2 0,0 0,0 3l1,1h-1v1a13,13 0,0 1,-2 4l-1,-1ZM260,88c-1,0 -1,0 0,0a8,8 0,0 1,1 0s1,0 0,0a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0ZM259,85v-1a1,1 0,0 0,0 -1l1,-1v1a1,1 0,0 0,0 1l-1,1ZM255,77h-1v-1h1a1,1 0,0 0,1 -1,2 2,0 0,0 0,-1l2,3h-1v1a2,2 0,0 0,-1 0l-1,-1ZM211,78a6,6 0,0 1,0 -3h1l1,3h-2ZM265,77a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1h1a1,1 0,0 1,-1 1ZM248,75a7,7 0,0 1,1 -1l1,-1a3,3 0,0 1,0 2h-2ZM254,75a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1v1ZM255,74a6,6 0,0 0,0 -1v1ZM253,73a1,1 0,0 1,0 -1v1ZM256,72 L255,71 256,72c1,1 0,1 0,0ZM252,71a1,1 0,0 1,-1 0h1c1,0 0,0 0,0ZM254,70a2,2 0,0 0,-1 0l-2,-1 -1,-2a3,3 0,0 0,0 -1c0,-2 1,-2 2,0a2,2 0,0 1,0 1v2l1,1a1,1 0,0 1,1 0c1,0 1,1 0,0ZM239,65c-1,-1 0,-2 1,-2v1l-1,1ZM250,60a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0v-2h1v2ZM256,50a2,2 0,0 0,0 -1v-1a2,2 0,0 1,1 2h-1ZM258,49 L259,48v1h-1ZM260,48 L257,47a2,2 0,0 1,-1 0,3 3,0 0,0 1,-1 1,1 0,0 1,1 0l2,-1c2,-1 2,-2 1,-3 0,-2 0,-2 1,-1 1,0 2,1 1,2a3,3 0,0 0,1 1v2a2,2 0,0 1,-2 1l-1,1h-1ZM260,39v-3a8,8 0,0 0,2 1l1,1v1h-3Z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.5" />
</vector>
```